# How to identify pinout of ATmega 2560 derivative board?

Tags: atmega2560

My 3d printer, Creality Ender 4, has an ATmega 2560 chip based card, and I need to identify the number associated with a particular Pin.
I read, on the official Arduino website, a simple tutorial in which through a small led connected to two pins of the card, you wrote a code (sketch) that made it turn on, but you had to know the Pin number.
I would like to do this on my board, I unplug all cables (power supply, motors, etc.) and connect it to the PC via USB and from Arduino IDE, I execute the code, connecting the LED on the ground and on the signal (see image).[image]
To identify the Pin number I thought I would go to exclusion, because I know all the PIN numers of the chip, until the LED lights up.
So I ask, is that correct? is there a chance of damaging the card? or is there a better method?
Thanks in advance

Comment: not correct because the microcontoller pins are not directly connected to peripheral plugs on the board ... yes, the board could be damaged ... it is better to obtain a schematic diagram or at least a table of pin functions

Comment: The 3dpinter/board manufacturer don't want give me the schematics, or just the number I need. On the internet there is very little info about the board...

Comment: I'd suggest using a multimeter in continuity mode, on the **unpowered** board. Then check which MCU pin is connected to the pin you're looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect everything but the switch.
Run this:

```
for each pin,
  set the pin to INPUT_PULLUP mode;
  do,
    read and print the pin number and pin state;
  until operator touches a key;
  read and discard the serial input;
end;
```

You do:

- Each time a new pin number prints on the terminal,
  toggle the switch a few times to confirm whether you are seeing the result of your actions.
- If not, touch the spacebar to try the next pin #
- else, you found it.